# nginx http-proxy infront of PHP-App running on Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, drupal-7, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, http-proxy

i am very new to AWS and Beanstalk so maybe my question is very easy...

I want to put up a Drupal-Page (with boost) on Beanstalk as PHP-App (PHP + Apache).
And i would like to use nginx as a reserve proxy infront of it. My simple question:
**How to do this? And is it a good idea?**

I searched the internet and all the tutorials i found were assuming that i run the server. But i couldnt figure out how to use an nginx http-proxy infront of PHP-App running on Beanstalk... unfortunatly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set-up a 2-tier infra within Elastic Beanstalk and then perhaps with an ELB in front
ELB->Nginx->Drupal
However, for the added cost of that instance, not many people run this set-up. At least not within a small set-up that Beanstalk is likely running.

Comment: Would it be possible (and reasonable) to install and configure nginx on each additional instance and set the http-proxy on each of them seperatly up? So to say an http-proxy per instance

Comment: Yes but you have to think what are you gaining? If you are using Nginx to take the static load from Drupal, if they're on the same server this is self-defeating. What will you use Nginx for?